# Kendo UI posting null values to paramter in web api controller method

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using the following code in cshtml,
Controller display null value in parameter,
I require values to be populated in controller method parameter,
Please help

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:49885/api",
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Get"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: function(data) {
                            debugger;
                            //return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers/" + JSON.stringify(data.models[0]);

                            return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers";
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Put",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: function(data) {
                            debugger;
                            return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers/" + JSON.stringify(data.SupplierId);

                            //return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers";
                        },
                        //url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Delete",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                            //return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers/" + JSON.stringify(data);

                            return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers";
                        },
                        //url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Suppliers",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Post",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        //data: JSON.stringify([data.SupplierId, data.CommId])
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                        debugger;
                        if (operation !== "read" && options) {
                            return { models: JSON.stringify(options) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: false,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    data: function(data) { //specify the array that contains the data
                        return data || [];
                    },
                    errors: function(response) {
                        return response.error;
                    },
                    model: {
                        id: "SupplierId",
                        fields: {
                            SupplierId: { validation: { required: true } },
                            CommId: { validation: { required: true } },
                            EmailId: { validation: { required: true } },
                            FullName: { validation: { required: true } },
                            FirstName: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Description: { validation: { required: true } },
                            LastName: { validation: { required: true } },
                            StateId: { validation: { required: true } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            pageable: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [
                "SupplierId",
                { field: "SupplierId", title: "SupplierId", width: 120 },
                { field: "CommId", title: "CommId", width: 120 },
                { field: "EmailId", title: "EmailId", width: 120 },
                { field: "FullName", width: 120 },
                { field: "FirstName", width: 120 },
                { field: "Description", width: 120 },
                { field: "LastName", width: 120 },
                { field: "StateId", width: 120 },
                { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 150 }
            ],
            editable: true
        });
    });
    </script>
<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?